# return array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the solution but Is there any other nicer way to do in javascript or is it possible to modify the arr1 itself and have arr1 as array of objects alone

I have array of objects and string

```
arr1 = [{
    id: 'id1',
    name: 'name1'
}, {
    id: 'id2',
    name: 'name2'
}, '/roll', '/roll1'];
```

i would like to have array of objects alone at the end

```
newarr1 = [{
    id: "id1",
    name: "name1"
}, {
    id: "id2",
    name: "name2"
}]
```

current solution

```
arr1.map((item) => {
    if (typeof item === 'object') return newarr1.push(item)
})
```

Comment: Never use map where you need a forEach. `let newArr1 = []; arr1.forEach((item) => { if (typeof item === 'object') newarr1.push(item); });`

Answer (score 4):

```
newArr = arr1.filter(item => typeof item === 'object')
```

Comment: Nice answer:) This is not needed for OP's case, but a good-to-know: arrays are considered objects too, and if OP has nested arrays and wants to include/exclude them, an additional check for `Array.isArray(item)` is going to help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
const isObject = item => Object.getPrototypeOf(item) === Object.prototype;

const newarr1 = arr1.filter(isObject);
```

---

Demo

```js
const isObject = item => Object.getPrototypeOf(item) === Object.prototype;

const arr1 = [{id: 'id1', name: 'name1'}, {id: 'id2', name: 'name2'}, '/roll', '/roll1'];
const newarr1 = arr1.filter(isObject);

console.log(newarr1);
```